# How to check the validity of the form in docusign REST API?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

I want to check the time after which the form will get expired in docusign through REST API.

Comment: What does the Docusign documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  https://{environment}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountID}/envelopes/{envelopeID}/notification

The response will show you the expiration date:

```
{
"reminders": {
"reminderEnabled": "false",
"reminderDelay": "3",
"reminderFrequency": "1"
},
"expirations": {
"expireEnabled": "true",
"expireAfter": "10",
"expireWarn": "0"
}
}
```